# How to Fix Bluriness of SpriteKit-style SegmentedController element

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game using SpriteKit in Swift for iOS. I am implementing a settings panel with UI-style elements. I wanted to add a UISegmentedControl element, but I was unable to find a quick and easy way to add UIKit element into my scene that didn't require me creating 2-3 new files and adding 100+ lines of code. So, I instead decided to implement my own version of the UISegmentedControl element using an SKCropNode and SKShapeNodes. I have managed to do this without too much trouble, but the text in my SKLabelNodes appears blurry when I simulate the app.

The problem is that the text appears blurry when the app is simulated in landscape mode. In portrait mode the text looks pretty crisp, but in landscape mode it is a little blurry.

Here is the Class file

```
import SpriteKit

class SegController {
    var mainNode: SKShapeNode
    var itemShapes = [SKShapeNode]()


var segIndex = 0

init(withSize size: CGSize, withItems items: [String]) {
    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    var maskSize = size
    maskSize.width -= 3.5; maskSize.height -= 4
    let mask = SKShapeNode(rectOf: maskSize, cornerRadius: 5)
    mask.fillColor = UIColor.white
    cropNode.maskNode = mask
    mainNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: maskSize, cornerRadius: 5)
    mainNode.addChild(cropNode)
    mainNode.lineWidth = 2.5
    mainNode.strokeColor = UIColor.black

    var loopIndex = 0
    for _ in items {
        let itemShapeWidth = size.width / CGFloat(items.count)
        let itemShape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: itemShapeWidth, height: size.height))
        itemShape.lineWidth = 0.5
        itemShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black

        var xPos = itemShapeWidth * (CGFloat(loopIndex))
        xPos -= size.width / 2
        xPos += itemShapeWidth / 2
        itemShape.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: 0)

        cropNode.addChild(itemShape)
        itemShapes.append(itemShape)

        let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
        let fontSize = (8 + size.height / 6)
        label.fontSize = fontSize
        let yPos = -fontSize / 2.5
        label.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPos)
        label.name = "label"

        label.text = items[loopIndex]
        itemShape.addChild(label)

        if loopIndex == 0 {
            itemShape.fillColor = UIColor.black
            label.fontColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            itemShape.fillColor = UIColor.white
            label.fontColor = UIColor.black
        }

        loopIndex += 1
    }

}

func handleTap(withTouch touch: UITouch) {
    let location = touch.location(in: mainNode)
    var loopIndex = 0
    for itemShape in itemShapes {
        if itemShape.contains(location) && segIndex != loopIndex{
            itemShape.fillColor = UIColor.black
            let newLabel = getLabel(ofItem: itemShape)!
            newLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
            itemShapes[segIndex].fillColor = UIColor.white
            let oldLabel = getLabel(ofItem: itemShapes[segIndex])
            oldLabel?.fontColor = UIColor.black
            segIndex = loopIndex
            return
        }
        loopIndex += 1
    }

}

func getLabel(ofItem item: SKShapeNode) -> SKLabelNode? {
    for child in item.children {
        if child.name == "label" {
            return child as? SKLabelNode
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

And here is the necessary code for adding an instance of the class to the GameScene.swift file:

```
let segControlOne = SegController(withSize: CGSize(width: 400 , height: 60), withItems: ["One","Two"])

self.addChild(segControlOne.mainNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a lot less calculation while creating the SKLabelNode. This is an almost expected behavior, as SKLabelNode is optimized for performance against precision, so you can try to force your calculation to always use whole numbers. Play with the horizontalAlignmentMode to center it and round to whole number. I generally use UiKit for all the static graphic I need and SpriteKit for the game elements.